# does iad banner not need setting?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, iad, banner-ads

http://bees4honey.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-add-iad-banner-in-iphoneipad-app/

I already do something like that link.. and it is working..

but I am still confuse, is the IAd already done? or I have to setting first become my simple application launch?

because when I run that application at simulator the banner show "Test Advertisement" and also with a real device..

If I have to setting the IAd, can anyone tell me how I can do that?

firstly, thanks

basically we put that iad thingy. insert that in application. publish the application and wait money coming in?

Am I seeing test ads because I haven't published my ads yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that iAd is running on your simulator and real device. So you are done with iAd. I thought you have configured iAd in iTunes account. So no need to change any settings.

Comment: what do you mean by configuring iad in itunes? Does apple have ads for indonesian. Is this the issue?

Comment: basically we put that iad thingy. insert that in application. publish the application and wait money coming in?

Comment: Configuring means you have to login to iTunes account->Manage Your Applications-> Setup iAd Network then read the text there and check yes.. I didn't do after that.. And One More thing is My friend worked on iAd they told that the iAd is not showing in india. But Don't know about indonesia..

Comment: you mean developer account? where will the money go?

Comment: I don't know exactly about the accounts but I thought that the money will go to the account which is subscribed with $99 or $299. But you need not worry about Ads. iAd encounters some problems in some Countries. So It's Better to use GOOgle AdMob SDK to show ads.. Its Very Simple compared to iAd.